# Valgrind Memory Leak Wrong File Trace

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm currently in the memory-leak detection stage of debugging, and am running `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` on my executable. However, I'm getting some confusing output in a loss record:

```
==26628== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 343
==26628==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26628==    by 0x436EF6: void std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_range_insert<char*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsig$
==26628==    by 0x4368EF: giga::Page::aux_load() (stl_vector.h:1291)
==26628==    by 0x43499D: cachepp::SerialCache<cachepp::SimpleSerialCacheData, giga::Page>::allocate(std::shared_ptr<giga::Page> const&) (lineinterface.template:34)
...
```

The problem is in the trace for `giga::Page::aux_load` -- this function is defined by me, and most definitely *not* in the standard lib. I'm not sure why the line was not reported on this output line from the appropriate *calling file*.

I wasn't sure if code was necessary for this, but in case I do --

```
void giga::Page::aux_load() {
    this->data.clear();
    // deallocate the data vector
    std::vector<uint8_t>().swap(this->data);

    if(!this->get_is_dirty()) {
            // load data into the page
            FILE *fp = fopen(this->get_filename().c_str(), "r");
            if(fseek(fp, this->file_offset, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
                    throw(exceptionpp::RuntimeError("giga::Page::aux_load", "invalid result returned from fseek"));
            }

            char *data = (char *) calloc(this->get_size(), sizeof(char));

            if(fread((void *) data, sizeof(char), this->get_size(), fp) < this->get_size()) {
                    throw(exceptionpp::RuntimeError("giga::Page::aux_load", "invalid result returned from fread"));
            }
            fclose(fp);

            this->data.insert(this->data.end(), data, data + this->get_size());

            free((void *) data);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code has a memory leak if you throw the exception `throw(exceptionpp::RuntimeError`.  Why didn't you use a `std::vector<char>` instead of using `calloc`?

Comment: Using `data` as you local var name and `data` as your member name doesn't exactly help matters much in terms of clarity either. And `2 of 343` tells us there is quite a bit you're *not* showing us, but I'm betting the thing that *owns* that vector (the page) is likewise being leaked. Thus the "indirect" notation in the valgrind report.

Comment: Also, you have a dangling open file pointer if you throw an exception.  I think it's time you learn RAII techniques, since your code is a classic example of what happens if it isn't used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be caused by valgrind stacktrace not showing inlined function call
defined at stl_vector.h:1291 and called somewhere inside aux_load.

The next version of Valgrind has support for showing inlined function,
using the option --read-inline-info=yes.

So, get and compile the latest valgrind svn version
See http://www.valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html
for instruction about how to get, configure and compile the valgrind svn version

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the reason for the leaks in your report, but your code definitely will leak memory, without a doubt.  It will leak if you throw an exception:

`throw(exceptionpp::RuntimeError("giga::Page::aux_load", "invalid result returned from fread"));`

The reason why it is a leak is that you previously called `calloc`, and the line where you `free` the data is never reached.  You also have a dangling open file pointer if any exception is thrown by your function.

The answer to correct this is short and sweet:

1. Use `std::ifstream`, not `FILE*`.  This will guarantee that your file is closed on function return, regardless of the reason for the return.
2. Use `std::vector<char> dataV(get_size())`, not `calloc`.  This will guarantee that the memory is deallocated on function return, regardless of the reason for the return (in this case, use `&dataV[0]` or if using C++11 `dataV.data()` to get a pointer to the char buffer).

The topic you should read about is RAII:  [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)

Rewrite your code using these constructs above, and you will relieve yourself of the leaks in the function you posted.

The other changes you should use:

1. Check for `get_size() == 0`.  If it's 0, then you can return immediately without having to open files.
2. There is no need for you to use `this->` everywhere.  It clutters the code and makes it harder to debug if there is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful in terms of fixing the leak, and I will definitely refactor my code to be more robust -- however, I'm not sure if that addresses the original question (perhaps I wasn't very clear): why is the line reported in the relevant function not in a user file, but a file from the standard lib?

Comment: Also, regarding the use of 'this' in code -- I actually find it helpful because I know immediately that the functions and values were not defined ad hoc, or within the local function, but rather in the class scope -- for me at least, it improves the workflow. I'll read more into this, but I assume from what you suggested that this isn't standard programming practice?

Comment: @mzhang Leaks can be caused by not properly destroying `giga` objects in your program.  For example, if `giga` is derived from a base class, and you're creating `giga` object dynamically through a base class pointer, the base class needs a virtual destructor.  That is only one scenario.  Since you didn't post your whole code, given what you did post, I would bet that you're doing things similar to what you were doing in this function -- that is creating objects dynamically, and never getting to the point where these are objects are deallocated properly.